# SkiaSharp draw to window

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphics, 2d, skia

How can I open a window and draw to it with SkiaSharp (without using winforms, wpf or anything like that)? I've tried using SFML.Net instead of SKIA but it lacks a lot of features (rounded rectangle, shadow, gradient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using [Silk.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/Silk.NET) SFML bindings to create a GL context for Skia.

[This pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/Silk.NET/blob/feature/skia-silk-lab/src/Lab/Experiments/SilkBackedSkiaRendering/Program.cs) was very helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [perma link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/Silk.NET/main/src/Lab/Experiments/SilkBackedSkiaRendering/Program.cs) to the file linked.